# Java class not correctly running methods from another class

Tags: java, class, user-interface

First off, I apologize for the bad title. I had a hard time trying to describe this error. I have a GUI application that I am making with the following classes: [Click here to see my classes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTZ0C.png) I have come across a very weird problem where class Settings can be accessed in GUI but not Lottery. In GUI, I can can call methods through the Settings object I created in GUI, and it works. However, when I call them from Lottery is returns nothing or 0.
I have already created a Settings object in Lottery. I run this code below when I click a button after values in Settings have been set.

```
public void initialize(){
    teams = settings.getTeams();
    pick = settings.getNumberOfTeams();
    //Returns nothing ^
    //teams and pick is a local varible
}
```

The above varibles are nothing, even though I set them. And I know they have already been set, because if I called getTeams() from within the Settings class, it will return the correct values below.

```
public void addTeam(String name, String wins, String losses){
    teams.add(new Team(name, wins, losses));
    System.out.println(teams.size() - 1 + " " + teams.get(teams.size() -   1));
    System.out.println("Number of teams (SETTINGS): " + getNumberOfTeams());
}
```

However when called from Lottery, it stays nothing. But when I call Settings from GUI is does correctly return but not any other class. Note: Each class, a separate Settings object is created. 
Another interesting thing is that my IDE, says that the method can be private, even though I clearly call it from another class above. See that here: [It's hard to see but Public is highlighted saying it can be private](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqxHL.png)

I am usually good at finding errors, but this one has stumped me for about a week. Anything would help. I will also put the full Lottery and Settings classes below if that helps. Just note: The local variables in Settings are already set, and can be accessed within Settings itself.

Lottery Class:

```
public class Lottery {
Settings settings = new Settings();

private Random rand = new Random();
private int randNum;
private int pick;
private ArrayList<Team> draftOrder = new ArrayList<Team>(0);
private ArrayList<Team> teams = new ArrayList<Team>(0);
private boolean lotteryDone;

public Lottery(){}

public void initialize(){
    teams = settings.getTeams();
    System.out.println("Lottery team size: " + teams.size());
    pick = settings.getNumberOfTeams();
    System.out.println("Number of Teams (From lottery): " + pick);
    System.out.println("Number of teams (LOTTO): " + pick);
    System.out.println("Test..." + settings.getDraftRounds());
    teams.add(settings.getTeam(1));
    System.out.println("Other method test: " + teams.get(0));
    }

public void setDraftOrder(){
    while (teams.size() > 0){
        randNum = rand.nextInt(teams.size() - 1);
        System.out.println(randNum);
        draftOrder.add(teams.remove(randNum));
        System.out.println(draftOrder.get(0));
    }
}

public void getNextPick(){
     if (pick > 0){
     randNum = rand.nextInt(teams.size() - 1);
     draftOrder.add(pick, teams.remove(randNum));
     pick -= 1;
     }
}

public int getPickNumber(){
    return pick;
}

public Team getCurrentPick(int i){
    return draftOrder.get(i);
}

public ArrayList<Team> getDraftOrder(){
    return draftOrder;
}

public boolean lotteryDone(){
    if (lotteryDone){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Settings Class:

```
public class Settings {
private ArrayList<Team> teams = new ArrayList<Team>(0);
private Boolean skipLottery;
private Boolean autoSelectPick;
private int autoSelectPickTimer;
private int totalMoney;
private int yellowOverlay;
private int draftRounds;
private int draftPickTimer;
private int draftTickTimer;
private int currentRound;
private int currentPick;
private boolean lotteryInitialized;
private boolean draftInitialized;
private boolean auctionInitialized;

public void addTeam(String name, String wins, String losses){
    teams.add(new Team(name, wins, losses));
    System.out.println(teams.size() - 1 + " " + teams.get(teams.size() - 1));
    System.out.println("Number of teams (SETTINGS): " + getNumberOfTeams());
}

public boolean settingsDone(){
    if (teams.size() != 0 && totalMoney != 0 && yellowOverlay != 0 && draftRounds != 0 && draftPickTimer != 0 && draftTickTimer != 0){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

public void clearSettings(){
    teams.clear();
    skipLottery = false;
    autoSelectPick = false;
    autoSelectPickTimer = 0;
    totalMoney = 0;
    yellowOverlay = 0;
    draftRounds = 0;
    draftPickTimer = 0;
    draftTickTimer = 0;
    currentRound = 0;
    currentPick = 0;
    lotteryInitialized = false;
    draftInitialized = false;
    auctionInitialized = false;
}

public void setSkipLottery(boolean i){
    skipLottery = i;
}

public boolean getSkipLottery(){
    return skipLottery;
}

public void setAutoSelectPick(boolean i){
    autoSelectPick = i;
}

public boolean getAutoSelectPick(){
    return autoSelectPick;
}

public void setAutoSelectPickTimer(int i){
    autoSelectPickTimer = i;
}

public int getAutoSelectPickTimer(){
    return autoSelectPickTimer;
}

public void setTotalMoney(int i){
    totalMoney = i;
}

public int getTotalMoney(){
    return totalMoney;
}

public void setYellowOverlay(int i){
    yellowOverlay = i;
}

public int getYellowOverlay(){
    return yellowOverlay;
}

public void setDraftRounds(int i){
    draftRounds = i;
}

public int getDraftRounds(){
    return draftRounds;
}

public void setDraftPickTimer(int i){
    draftPickTimer = i;
}

public void setDraftTickTimer(int i){
    draftTickTimer = i;
}

public ArrayList<Team> getTeams(){
    return teams;
}

public Team getTeam(int index){
    return teams.get(index);
}

public int getNumberOfTeams(){
    return teams.size();
}

public int getDraftPickTimer(){
    return draftPickTimer;
}

public int getDraftTickTimer(){
    return draftTickTimer;
}

public void setLotteryInitialized(boolean i){
    lotteryInitialized = i;
}

public boolean getLotteryInitialized(){
    return lotteryInitialized;
}

public void setDraftInitialized(boolean i){
    draftInitialized = i;
}

public boolean getDraftInitialized(){
    return draftInitialized;
}

public void setAuctionInitialized(boolean i){
    auctionInitialized = i;
}

public boolean getAuctionInitialized(){
    return auctionInitialized;
}
```

Comment: My guess is you have more than one Settings object, one you are setting and the other you are reading.  I would step through the code in your debugger to see where this value is set and why it is not what you expected.

Comment: Use the debugger. Step you thru the code. Look at the amount of typing and formatting you had to do when a simple breakpoint would suffice

Comment: Search your code for `new Settings()`. It should occur once and only once. If multiple times, then as @PeterLawrey suggests, you have multiple objects, one that is updated, the others not. Learn about references and how to pass them where needed, and you'll solve your problem. If you need our help, you'll need to create and post a valid [mcve] -- and **not** a link to code.

Comment: Beyond that: your classes are way too big. Having more than lets say 5 fields is very often an indication that your "object model" could be improved. A class should have **one** responsibility; and contain exactly those fields required for that **one** job. Your lottery class knows about teams, random, draft order, picks, and so on. If it would be smaller, then *understanding* what it does would not require the help from other people ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"Note: Each class, a separate Settings object is created."*
This is the cause of your problem.

You have multiple instances of your Setting class. Which means you cannot access fields set on a different instance.

When you write
`Setting settings = new Settings();`
in the Lottery class, you are creating a new instance of your settings class. So none of the fields are populated.

To fix this problem you need to have a centralized Settings object. Only make one instance of Settings in the class that connects everything (GUI?) and write/read from that class. You can pass that one instance of Settings from GUI to the Lottery class and it will retain all of your assigned fields.

Also, it seems that your Settings object is missing a constructor and what you have in the Lottery.initialize() method should be in the (currently empty) constructor. You should initialize your settings with at least a general constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The reason I don't have a constructor is because I need to create the Lottery when a button is clicked, but I still need the Lottery object accessible throughout the class. How would I go about doing this?